# Single sign-on to JIRA v9.5 server failed

Tags: single-sign-on, jira, jira-plugin

Jira server 9.5 version
plugin Microsoft Azure Active Directory single sign-on for JIRA

On Azure, the login status is successful but jira cannot be logged in
[image]
[image]
File logs catalina.out

2023-12-05 03:09:43,273+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.r.internal.configuration.ConfigurationLoggerJob] Periodic rate limiting configuration log. System rate limiting settings: [SystemRateLimitingSettings(mode=OFF, bucketSettings=TokenBucketSettings(capacity=50, fillRate=10, intervalFrequency=1, intervalTimeUnit=Seconds), jobControlSettings=SystemJobControlSettings(reportingDbArchivingJobFrequencyDuration=PT1M10S, reportingDbRetentionPeriodDuration=PT24H, bucketCollectionJobFrequencyDuration=PT5M, bucketCleanupJobFrequencyDuration=PT15M, settingsReloadJobFrequencyDuration=PT1M))]
2023-12-05 03:09:43,713+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] Running start-index-recovery
2023-12-05 03:09:43,973+0000 Caesium-1-2 INFO [c.a.jira.startup.CacheWarmerLauncher] Warming up 3 caches.
2023-12-05 03:09:44,153+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Ensuring index correctness for operations in the last {1 days, 0 hours, 36 minutes, and 59 seconds}. (Note: it's an intentionally wider range)
2023-12-05 03:09:44,154+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Progress=30%, task=Catch up, message=Re-indexing issues modified in the last {1 days, 0 hours, 36 minutes, and 59 seconds}. (Versioning short-circuit checks are enabled.)
2023-12-05 03:09:45,352+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Progress=80%, task=Updating issue index with recent changes, message=There were no issue changes, skipping.
2023-12-05 03:09:45,461+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Progress=85%, task=Updating index with recent changes, message=There were no comment changes, skipping.
2023-12-05 03:09:45,920+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Progress=90%, task=Updating index with recent changes, message=There were no worklog changes, skipping.
2023-12-05 03:09:45,921+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] [INDEX-FIXER] Progress=95%, task=Catch up, message=Done catching up. Potentially outdated issues were updated in the index. Any deleted issues (plus comments & worklogs) in this range were removed from the index. 206 issues, 17 comments and 245 worklogs scanned. 0 issues, 0 comments and 0 worklogs reindexed. 3 issues, 0 comments and 7 worklogs deindexed. It took 138.2 ms to read from DB, 1.386 s to reindex, 241.5 ms to deindex, 1.767 s in total
2023-12-05 03:09:45,921+0000 Caesium-1-1 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.startup.IndexRecoveryLauncher] Finished start-index-recovery
created com.atlassian.jira.plugins.webhooks.ao.WebhookDaoImpl@7b5ed407 2069812231 with events jira:issue_updated
AO_4AEACD_WEBHOOK_DAO {ID = 1} 56097
AI: INFO 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Configuration file has been successfully found as resource
AI: INFO 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: 'MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity': null value is replaced with '500'
AI: INFO 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: 'FlushIntervalInSeconds': null value is replaced with '5'
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Using Http Client version 4.3+
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: No back-off container defined, using the default 'EXPONENTIAL'
AI: INFO 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: 'Channel.MaxTransmissionStorageCapacityInMB': null value is replaced with '10'
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.MyContextInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.MyContextInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryInitializer not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to scan packages 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights': exception: 'org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersBundleURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection'
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Default performance counters will be automatically loaded.
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Windows performance counters are not relevant on this OS.
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Failed to create performance module: 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.perfcounter.WebPerformanceCounterModule'
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:09, 41: Error while creating performance counters: 'com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean'
2023-12-05 03:10:04,735+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.UpgradeScheduler] Running scheduled upgrades
2023-12-05 03:10:04,744+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.LoggingUpgradeService] run upgrades has started
2023-12-05 03:10:04,869+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.j.upgrade.util.BuildNumberDao] Setting current build number to 950000
2023-12-05 03:10:04,877+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.UpgradeIndexManager] There are no reindex requests of type [IMMEDIATE, DELAYED] so none will be run
2023-12-05 03:10:04,878+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.j.upgrade.util.BuildNumberDao] Setting current version to 9.5.0
2023-12-05 03:10:04,878+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.j.upgrade.util.BuildNumberDao] Setting downgrade version to 7.1.2
2023-12-05 03:10:04,909+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.LoggingUpgradeService] run upgrades has finished successfully, and took 164 milliseconds to process.
2023-12-05 03:10:04,910+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.UpgradeScheduler] JIRA upgrades completed successfully
2023-12-05 03:10:04,969+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.UpgradeScheduler] Plugins upgrades completed successfully
2023-12-05 03:10:04,973+0000 Caesium-1-4 INFO ServiceRunner [c.a.jira.upgrade.UpgradeIndexManager] Reindexing is not allowed after this upgrade and there is no immediate reindex requests

2023-12-05 03:10:20,077+0000 Caesium-1-2 INFO [c.a.jira.startup.CacheWarmerLauncher] Warmed cache(s) in 36100 ms.
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:10, 31: InProcessTelemetryChannel sending telemetry
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:10, 33: InProcessTelemetryChannel sending telemetry
AI: ERROR 05-12-2023 03:10, 613: Failed to send, Bad request : {"itemsReceived":1,"itemsAccepted":0,"errors":[{"index":0,"statusCode":400,"message":"Telemetry item length must not exceed 65536"}]}
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:12, 28: InProcessTelemetryChannel sending telemetry
AI: TRACE 05-12-2023 03:12, 39: InProcessTelemetryChannel sending telemetry

Is it related to the following 2 errors?
Failed to create com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule, com.springapp.mvc.extensions.WebRequestRunIdTelemetryModule not found by com.microsoft.MicrosoftSsoJiraPlugin [202]
Failed to scan packages 'com.microsoft.applicationinsights': exception: 'org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersBundleURLConnection cannot be cast to java.net.JarURLConnection'